# Is it possible for radon to exist at consistent levels in an atmosphere for 10,000 years?

Tags: science-based, atmosphere, radioactivity

On an alien planet, could it be possible for a foreign species of aliens to somehow convert the atmosphere to consist of a small amount of radon (10% or less) for a fairly long amount of time (around 10,000 years)? Since radon has a half life of 3.8 days (specifically radon-222) It wouldn't be able to last for this long normally and thus the aliens would have to constantly renew the amount of radon. However, I want the alien race to disappear afterwards, and have the radon continue to last. Would there be a way to either extend the half-life or automatically keep creating radon without littering the planet with a large amount of uranium-238?

If this isn't plausible, are there any other radioactive gases that would last this long?

Comment: You mean of course a large amount of uranium-238. Radium-226 has a half-life of 1600 years, and for this reason exists only as a decay product of uranium-238.

Comment: @AlexP Ah, my bad, I thought they were two unrelated isotopes. I edited the post to fix that.

Comment: If you can maintain the temperatures on the planet in the lowish 4000C range, you could have an uranium vapor rich atmosphere (boiling point 4404 K). A good point about that temperature - most volatiles in the atmosphere boil away in space and you can have a 10% atmosphere of really heavy elements (such as radon, with atomic weight of 222 u)

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi That's good to know! Unfortunately the planet has an average temperature of -9ºC, but i'll have to keep that in mind for future ventures, thanks!

Comment: You can get away with a lot less source material if you start from U-234.  That won't address the fact that the atmosphere will be nearly instantly blasted into space by the intense heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not an earthlike atmosphere, to create an earthlike atmosphere that is 10% Radon-222, by mass, you'd have to be producing ~515x10<sup>15</sup> tonnes of gas every 3.8 days, requiring the decay of ~525x10<sup>15</sup> tonnes of Radium-226, that's ~1.6x10<sup>12</sup> kg per second. The Radium decay produces 4.6MeV per atom for a total output of ~17.4x10<sup>24</sup> Watts, you'd boil the entire atmosphere into space almost instantaneously.

In fact the total binding energy of an Earthlike world is approximately 2.25x10<sup>32</sup>J
so if you tried to maintain the atmospheric Radon levels you'd evaporate the whole world in about six months flat. That's without going into the further decay chains and energy outputs needed to get you to the Radium from longer lived isotopes nor those that come from the Radon undergoing its own decay process to a stable isotope of Lead.

In theory if the aliens have overcome certain problems in atomic physics it could be possible for them to take a [supermassive stable isotope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Island_of_stability) and extract Radon nuclei directly and pump them into the atmosphere. Then we're back to the issue PcMan pointed out with the radioactive decay of the Radon itself which is more than enough to destroy the world.